# Is there an easy way in Scala to check whether resource by some URL respond with 404?

Tags: scala, url

I'm new to Scala and I have some URLs. I need to check whether those resources referenced by URLs are working or not? How can I achieve this with Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this with Scala's standard library. But there are several other libraries that help you with your problem.

I'll give you an explanation that shows how to do this with [Spray](http://spray.io). This solution has the advantage that it is non-blocking, but as you are new to Scala, the usage of `Future`s might be new to you.

First you need to add some dependencies to your project. The easiest way is if you use SBT. Add the following lines to your `build.sbt`.

```
resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

// Dependencies
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3"

libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-client" % "1.2.0"
```

Now the source code of your program looks quite easy and is also non-blocking:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.http._
import spray.client.pipelining._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }

object HTTPTest extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("http-test")
  import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures

  // take an http request and return a future of http response
  val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive


  // this method will give you *only* the status code for a URL as a Future
  def getStatusFor(url: String): Future[Int] =
    pipeline(Get(url)).map { x => x.status.intValue }

  // use it this way
  getStatusFor("http://server.org/help").onComplete {
    case Success(statusCode) => println(statusCode)
    case Failure(err) => // do something with the exception
  }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Is akka http still open source or is it a commercial licensed now? @pvorb

Comment: It's no longer under an OSI-recognized open source license, but that's all I know.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use an http access library to try and access the URL. Using play2's WS

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
val futureResponse:Future[Response] = WS.url("http://www.example.com/404.html").get()
```

then you can either use monadic operations to read the response and react

```
futureResponse.map {response => response.status==404} //will return a Future[Boolean]
```

or you can block until you actually have the response :

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val response =Await.result(futureResponse, 5 seconds)
if(response.status==404) {
  ???
}else{
  ???
}
```

There are other HTTP clients for scala such as [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since a URL is just a virtual reference to a web resource - it always works.  ;)

Additionally, you can read one line from the resource as text:

```
try {
  val text = Source.fromUrl(new java.net.URL(someString)).getLine
} catch {
  case java.io.IOException => // do something ...
}
```

OR read all lines from the resource as text:

```
try {
  val source = Source.fromUrl(new java.net.URL(someString))
  for (line <- source) {
    println(line)
    // do anything you like with each line of text
  }
} catch {
  case java.io.IOException => // do something ...
}
```

Or you can use java classes to connect to the resource and read it's length, etc ...:

```
try {
  val connection = (new java.net.URL(someString)).openConnection
  connection.connect;
  val l = connection.getContentLength
  // use the connection anyway you like
} catch {
  case java.io.IOException => // do something ...
}
```

Comment: In here, It gives the html code of the page. It works fine :) Is there a way to check **html respose code(404)** for check the url ?

Comment: `scala.io.Source` isn't suited for your problem. It won't give you access to the HTTP header.